# Display only 1 product's shipping option, of the two in a cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two separate products; 1 product for a Voucher that can be posted via mail/picked up and 1 product that can be shipped.

If I have both of the items on a cart, both of their shipping options show up. I'd like to only be able to display 1 product's shipping option.

I have tried using different plugins ie. Conditional Shipping for Woocommerce, Woocommerce Conditional Shipping and Payments, Advanced Flat Rate Shipping for Woocommerce.

What I didn't try is use php code to do this as I'm not experienced with coding and as much as possible, i'd like to do this on the dashboard.

I tried to do conditionals on the plugins to not show a product's shipping option but it always shows both of the product's shipping options.

Comment: do you have a screenshot of the cart/checkout page shipping section? By default, WooCommerce shipping rates are based on location, and not on the products in the cart (unless you use shipping classes and Flat Rate amounts by shipping class)

Comment: Yes, I tried to post a screenshot but it didn't take. I'll post it here and yes I'm using shipping classes and flat rates. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TiSZ.png

Comment: And if you go to the Flat Rate settings, under "Calculation type", do you have "Per Class:  Charge shipping for each shipping class"? If yes, try use "Per Order" instead

Comment: Yes, I have them "Per Order". https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbrC0.png

Comment: So there must be another problem. Screenshot of the whole Flat Rate settings please?

Comment: Here it is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfaXa.png

Question: is it a problem if i have multiple flat rate options?

Comment: Ok, instead of N/A try entering 0 to the other shipping class rates. If you have multiple Flat Rates, well, that could also be the problem then

Comment: I entered 0 on the N/A and it's still not solved. I have also tried to disable the other Flat Rates to see if that is the problem, but still, not solved.

Comment: Even after emptying the Cart and trying again?

Answer (score 0):

I learned this from @businessbloomer!
the first part is a function you can just leave in functions.
The second part checks the cart for the specific category and you can unset shipping methods based on if that cat is in the cart

```
// check for shipping class in cart
function cart_has_product_with_shipping_class($slug)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_in_cart = false;
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms    = get_the_terms($_product->id, 'product_shipping_class');
        if ($terms) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $_shippingclass = $term->slug;
                if ($slug === $_shippingclass) {
                    $product_in_cart = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $product_in_cart;
}


// remove all but desired for selected_category products
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_all_but_desired_if_selected_category', 99);
function hide_all_but_desired_if_selected_category($rates)
{
    $categories  = array('selected-category-slug');
    //if selected_category is in the cart
    if (woo_custom_category_is_in_the_cart($categories)) {
        unset($rates['table_rate:24:2']); // zone 1
        unset($rates['table_rate:22']); // zone 2
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

You can get those $rates by inspecting your cart shipping methods